# Usage and Heath Data Collection Logs auto deletes

Tags: sharepoint-server, logs

I have some enquires on the set of Logs from Usage and Health Data Collection, I was monitoring Administrative Actions, analytics usage and other logs, I realized that it auto deletes after 3 days.
My enquiry is:

1. I could not find any detail explanation if three days is the standard number of days or where to configure this in Central admin.
2. Or is it configured by file size limitation, and it gets deleted after x amount size the folder reaches. I could not find this option in central admin as well.

Hope someone could shed a light on this. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default retention days to store usage and health data collection logs is **14** days, and there is **NO** setting in the Central Administration to configure the `DaysRetained` from GUI, instead, you have only to use PowerShell to configure the usage `DaysRetained` parameter as below:

```
Get-SPUsageDefinition # to obtain the Event name and the current retention days
Set-SPUsageDefinition -Identity "SPUsageDefinition Event Name" -Enable -DaysRetained 14
```

> **Note:** DaysRetained only accepts values from 0 to 31 days.

**To configure Usage and Heath Data Collection Logs from Central Administration by doing the following:**

1. Open Central Administration as Administrator.
2. Click on `Monitoring`.
3. Below Reporting, Click on `Configure usage and health data collection` .
   [image]
4. On the Configure usage and health data collection page, in the Usage Data Collection section, select the Enable usage data collection check box.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I don't know why the logs mysteriously disappeared after 3 days, could it be someone before me had configured to 3 days? Also you mentioned that for usage and health data collection, the default retention is 14 days. I can't see number of days from central admin, but I realized diagnostic logs has a input for use to configure.

Comment: Use the PowerShell script to get the currently assigned values, and please don't forget to mark the answer as accepted in case it helps you!

Comment: Thank you very much for your help

Comment: I'm glad to hear that my answer helped you, please mark it as an accepted answer

Comment: I'm sorry I just realized that I am using SharePoint 2019, but I went through the documentation for administrative actions and it states that it is only for 2016! Do you have any idea why they crossed out 2019? But I am able to view the admin actions logs

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/using-administrative-actions-logging-in-sharepoint-server-2016